# Compiling Python File for Distribution

Tags: python, pip, exe

I have a really simple Python script. It’s written in a single file however I did have to install two things using pip. I’ve created this on Mac and I need to somehow compile it into a runnable application on windows. I’ve spent hours trying to use pyinstaller to make it into an exe file but I don’t think the dependencies are included in that ... I’ve also tried creating a virtual environment using venv but that doesn’t work either. I first tried using pyinstaller on Mac which was really easy but didn’t run at all when transferred it to windows. I then have been trying to do it on windows but it’s just very difficult and it’s just one error after another. I finally managed to build the app on windows using pyinstaller but it said “failed to execute script ...”

So does anyone know any simple way to make it into a runnable application? Doesn’t have to be an exe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pyinstaller is architecture and platform specific

Comment: Yeah I figured. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using py2app. To install it, type: `pip install py2app`.

Check out [This](http://www.marinamele.com/from-a-python-script-to-a-portable-mac-application-with-py2app) link for more information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I think py2app is for Mac. Although I wrote the Python on Mac, I wanted it to run on windows